# Vim in tmux does not correctly determine background color

Tags: terminal, vim, tmux

I connect to a server via SSH from xfce4-terminal.

When I open vim outside of tmux, colors in vim are very bright (which is good):
[image: bright colors in vim]

When I start tmux with default config, and open vim from there, it displays normal colors (t_Co=8):
[image: normal colors in vim]

However, if I set `default-terminal` to "**whatever**-256colors" (or start `tmux` with `-2`) , and start vim from tmux, some colors are very dim:
[image: dim colors in vim]

Vim does recognize that this is a 256-color terminal, since t_Co gets set to 256.

I found out that entering `:set background=dark` in vim fixes the colorscheme, however, that isn't the proper fix, because this only inverses the problem (i.e. it causes vim to use bright colors with a terminal with light background).

How do I make vim correctly determine background color while in tmux, without setting it explicitly?

---

Ouside of tmux, `$TERM` is equal to `xterm-256color`.

`.tmux.conf` contains:

```
set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"
```

Inside tmux, `$TERM` is `screen-256color`. Changing terminal type to `xterm-256color` didn't help.

Comment: Setting TERM to WHATEVER-256colors, as I already stated, doesn't help, -2 flag doesn't help. Setting default-terminal in .tmux.conf doesn't help.

Comment: @IporSircer the problem is that vim displays WRONG colors when tmux is configured to support 256 colors.

Comment: What's your `$TERM` in the first case, that is, outside of tmux?

Comment: @egmont It is xterm-256color.

Comment: @Christopher yep